# Showing the selected tab at center in ViewTabPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

In my project I am using ViewTabPager library https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator .
It's working fine but my requirement is when i select any tab i wanted to show the tab in center.Is it possible to do?
I wanted show the selected tab in center from the O position.

If you have any solution please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have this in my code and just works

```
@Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            int scrollX = (mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(position).getLeft() - (screenWidth / 2)) + (mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(position).getWidth() / 2);
            ((HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrlTabs)).scrollTo(scrollX, 0);
    }
```

hope this help